# WPF SplashScreen , how to make splashscreen showing longer

Tags: wpf

I found only one way to make splash display time longer.

That is changing ApplicationDefinition to Page and configuration it's time.

But I need ApplicationDefinition, I got locator here and it lost if I use page.

So I want to make SpashScreen display time and delay before showing main form longer but I also want to save ApplicationDefinition.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use the explicit way of showing the splash screen](http://tozon.info/blog/post/2008/08/11/Splash-Screen-in-WPF.aspx) and pass false to the Show method.

That way you have to call Close() explicitly when you want the splash to close.

Comment: SplashScreen works automatic with ApplicationDefinition on .net 4

Comment: Yes, but apparently it does not work the way you want because it only waits until all resources are loaded. If you want to adjust the time you have to explicitly show and close the splash screen.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Could you explain?

Comment: You said "it only waits until all resources are loaded" , so I need to slow down this time.

Comment: That is when you use the implicit way of showing the Splash Screen. When you use the explicit way you are in control.

Comment: But if I changing ApplicationDefinition to Page I have some troubles with MVVM Locator based on it. So I want to trick default method.

Answer (score 4):

I opened the App.xaml file, and made these changes to "delay" the showing.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    App()
    {
        // Pause to show the splash screen for 3 seconds
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: A vad solution that freezes the UI thread. Better use the TAP `await TaskEx.Delay(1000)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use, as Jake Glines wrote, `System.Threading`

```
using System.Threading;

public MainWindow()
{           
  SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("splash.jpg");
  splash.Show(true);
  Thread.Sleep(1500);           
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

Or you can use timer/progressbar on it, and  make it depend on real loading, not just imaginary.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to find the App.g.cs file and its Main():

```cs
       public static void Main() {
            SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen("splash.jpg");
            splashScreen.Show(true);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);           
            someNameSpace.App app = new someNameSpace.App();
            app.Run();
       }
```

Where the only newly added field is `Thread.Sleep(3000);`, which will delay the showing of the splash screen by 3 seconds.